# Grep for string from multiple file paths from list of files

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am currently learning bash scripting, wanted help in following issue.

There are 3 files containing list of file paths inside them: list1, list2, list3.

`list1` contains paths of multiple txt paths.

`list2` contains paths of multiple cfg paths.

`list3` contains paths of multiple bat paths.

**Example:**

```
list1:
./saved/nametxts/ptboy1.txt
./saved/nametxts/ptboy2.txt
./saved/nametxts/ppboy1.txt
./saved/nametxts/ppboy2.txt
./saved/nametxts/pgboy_a.txt

list2:
./saved/configs/names/ptboy1.cfg
./saved/configs/names/ptboy2.cfg
./saved/configs/names/ppboy1.cfg
./saved/configs/names/ppboy2.cfg
./saved/configs/names/pgboy_a.cfg

list3:
./saved/batches/confignames/ptboy1.bat
./saved/batches/confignames/ptboy2.bat
./saved/batches/confignames/ppboy1.bat
./saved/batches/confignames/ppboy2.bat
./saved/batches/confignames/pgboy_a.bat
```

I want to grep for

a name **John** from the files listed in **list1**

an ID **HS_J_1024** from files listed in **list2** and

profile history **hist_1024** from files listed in **list3**

Hence, from the above example,

**John** is searched in `./saved/nametxts/ptboy1.txt` and other following textfiles from `list1`

**HS_J_1024** is searched in `./saved/configs/names/ptboy1.cfg` and other following cfgfiles from `list2`

**hist_1024** is searched in `./saved/batches/confignames/ptboy1.bat` and other following batfiles from `list3`

User will give only path for these lists, such as:-

`./saved/namelists/list1`

`./saved/cfglists/list2`

`./saved/batlists/list3`

Then grep for name, ID and profile in all the files one by one.

Once name, ID, profile matches - the Bat file would get updated with:

"grepped today " at the end of `batfile`.

What I have tried now:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter name list file path: " filename
read -p "Enter CFG list file path: " filecfg
read -p "Enter bat list file path: " filebat

echo $filename
echo $filecfg
echo $filebat

#making one line through paste
paste $filename $filecfg $filebat > pastefile

#awk -F ' ' '{print $1 ":" $2}' pastefile
#file="pastefile"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" > printline
    #there are 3 parts (filepaths) - storing them one by one in a1(names), a2(cfg), a3(bat)
    awk '{print $1}' printline > a1
    awk '{print $2}' printline > a2
    awk '{print $3}' printline > a3
    chmod +x a1,a2,a3
    echo "grep -A 2 'John' a1 | sed 's?.............\$??' > a11" > a11
    echo "grep 'HS_J_1024' a2 > a12" > a12
    echo "grep 'hist_1024' a3 | sed -i 's?\$?grepped today?' a3" > a13
    chmod +x a11,a12,a13
    ./a11
    ./a12
    ./a13
done <pastefile
```

Here files **a1, a2, a3** are having proper file paths but the same is not reflecting when I try to grep. I am missing something to make this an input to the grep.

Could you please help me out?
I would grateful if you could suggest any other optimal way of doing this too.

Thank you

Note:  searching in the **files listed** in list1, list2 and list3, **not** in list1, list2 and list3 themselves.

Comment: Why do you `paste` your 3 files and then split the result again? Why not using the original 3 files? And why do you loop over `pastefile` to store the current line in variable `line` but not use it? Why don't you just `grep 'John' list1; grep 'HS_J_1024' list2; grep 'hist_1024' list3`?

Comment: The user inputs contains multiple filepaths. I would like to loop them over one by one. I tried to loop all 3 files though, but while loop could handle 1 file only here. Hence used `paste` to make it one line then use that file as input to the `while` loop. Please let me know if there is any other method of doing it in optimal way.

Comment: The problem is that there is absolutely no reason to loop. Why not simply doing a `grep` on each of your 3 files?

Comment: All those individual files are mapped `(ptboy.*)`. Once I grep for name, ID and profile, the `bat` should get updated. Example adding `grepped today <date-time-stamp>` at the end of `bat file` individually. Hence the loop.

Comment: I see. You are searching in the files listed in `list1`, `list2` and `list3`, not in `list1`, `list2` and `list3` themselves? If yes, please edit your question and make this clear.

Comment: Just for clarification: In your example file `list1`, there is no line having the word _John_, so it means you don't have a match, right?

Comment: @user1934428 They want to search in the files listed in `list1`, not in `list1` itself. Plus, they apparently want to search their 3 strings in triples of files (defined by the same line number in `list{1,2,3}`), not in any file of the lists. This second essential information is still missing in the question.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Then the OP wrote it incorrectly when saying  _want to grep for a name John from `list1`_. This should be _want to grep for a name John from one of the files listed in `list1`_.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I know, I already asked for clarifications and they added a final note about this, but still, the question is not crystal clear. In my humble opinion, it could be that in their mind `list1` is not a filename but literally the first of the 3 file lists. The confusion could come from the expression "_list file_" instead of "_file lists_". An English issue.

Comment: No reason for `perl` tag, removed it.

Comment: Kindly excuse me if the question was not completely clear. Made edits according to the suggestions from user1934428 and Renaud. Hope it is fine now.
Thank you for the answer @Renaud

Comment: @John809 You are still not explaining that `John`, `HS_J_1024` and `hist_1024` shall be searched in triples of files at the same position in the 3 lists. As you wrote your question `John` could be searched in any file of first list, `HS_J_1024` in any file of second list and `hist_1024` in any file of third list.

Comment: Edited again, thank you for such detail oriented suggestion. @Renaud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as in your example, your file names do not contain white spaces, you can try:

```
read -p "Enter name list file path: " filename
read -p "Enter CFG list file path: " filecfg
read -p "Enter bat list file path: " filebat
read -p "Enter first string to search for: " s1
read -p "Enter second string to search for: " s2
read -p "Enter third string to search for: " s3

while read -r a1 a2 a3; do
  if grep -qF "$s1" "$a1" && grep -qF "$s2" "$a2" && grep -qF "$s3" "$a3"; then
    printf 'grepped today\n' >> "$a3"
  fi
done < <(paste "$filename" "$filecfg" "$filebat")
```

If your file names can indeed contain white spaces you can store the content of your 3 files in bash arrays with `mapfile` and use these arrays in your loop:

```
mapfile -t l1 < "$filename"
mapfile -t l2 < "$filecfg"
mapfile -t l3 < "$filebat"

for (( i=0; i<${#l1[@]} && i<${#l2[@]} && i<${#l3[@]}; i++ )); do
  if grep -qF "$s1" "${l1[i]}" && grep -qF "$s2" "${l2[i]}" && grep -qF "$s3" "${l3[i]}"; then
    printf 'grepped today\n' >> "${l3[i]}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Trying right now

Comment: That's wonderful and worked like a charm, thank you so much for such quick help!!